# Nvidia not displaying correctly HDMI monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I have a laptop, Dell N5110, with nvidia 525m. I installed nvidia-331 driver which can be found in Ubuntu repo.

When I connect my hdmi all screens are randomly stretched and very chaotic. Some parts of the laptop screen are found in DVI screen and part in HDMI screen. Screens are overlapping, but when I separate them in arandr, after applying all changes it's still unusable.

I looked in `xrandr --query` and noticed that when all three screens are connected vga1 is shown as disconnected and strange virtual connected.

A similar situation occurs when there is only hdmi and laptop screen.

So basically Nvidia is not working correctly with HDMI port.

[image: how the screen looks]

Additionally there is an issue with stretching. Because when I  stretch to anything to full size it goes on both screens.

I checked `Xorg.conf` and it looks like this:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "intel"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "SNA"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

Shouldn't there be more info about all screens? Or maybe there is a specific file where I can configure nvidia and add some static values?

Comment: Have you tried it with "nvidia-settings"?

Comment: Till now, i didn't try but in Xserver information says that i have 
screens:1  and  is named as(Display name pcname:0). and when i click on Xscreen 0 information it's dimension is 2390x768

Comment: In my memory, there is an option in "nvidia-settings", as the two monitors are used.

Comment: i looked through  every menu part in nvidia-settings and didn't notice such option ;(.

Answer (score 1):

So after some experiments and with a little luck I found out that I had to regenerate my `xorg.conf` file using the command: `sudo nvidia-xconfig`. After that restart `lightdm` and that's it ;)

Additionally, in **Display Settings** (*not* `nvidia-settings`) you will probably have to choose to align all by laptop screen.